# How to make Yocto place all target RPMs for a specific package group to a separate directory?

Tags: package, yocto

I would appreciate your help with ideas how to perform the following.
I am trying to make a specific Yocto-based build, so I combined all mandatory packages into one separate package group and all optional (like debug tools, tests and stuff) into another. How can I make Yocto place all target RPMs for optional package group into a separate directory with all their dependencies, so I could install them onto target system when I need them? Is there any kind of an example?
I just can't figure out a technique how to make this in Yocto.
Thank you!